# Implement checkbox filtering using XSLT and JS on XML files

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, checkbox

I wish to implement checkbox filtering by category using XSLT. Something like this: [Filtering](http://outlet.us.dell.com/ARBOnlineSales/Online/InventorySearch.aspx?brandId=2201&c=us&cs=22&l=en&s=dfh)

In the backend, the XML file is structured as follows. I have no control over the format of this file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- note that fields is populated with every single category and value-->
<fields>
  <field name="category1">
    <value>cat1stuff1</value>
    <value>cat1stuff2</value>
    <value>cat1stuff3</value>
  </field>
  <field name="category2">
    <value>cat2stuff1</value>
    <value>cat2stuff2</value>
    <value>cat2stuff3</value>
  </field>
</fields>

<!--categories can contain 0, 1, or more values-->
<apps>
  <app id="App1">
    <name>Application 1</name>
    <desc>This is app 1</desc>
    <category1>
      <value>cat1stuff2</value>
    </category1>
    <category2/>
  </app>
  <app id="App2">
    <name>Application 2</name>
    <desc>This is app 2</desc>
    <category1>
      <value>cat1stuff1</value>
      <value>cat1stuff3</value>
    </category1>
    <category2>
      <value>cat2stuff3</value>
    </category2>
<apps>
```

I want to have checkboxes for each value within each category. The apps that have those values are then shown. The ones who don't have those values are hidden. Just like the dell site.

This is what I have for my XSLT file so far:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
 <xsl:output method="html"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="fields">
  <html>
   <body>
    <div id="testFilter">
     <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="field">
       <h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
       </h2>
       <xsl:for-each select="value">
        <label>
         <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" >
         </input>
         <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
         <br/>
        </label>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template> 

 <xsl:template match="apps">
  <html>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    <xsl:text>
     <!-- stuff goes here -->
    </xsl:text>
   </script>
   <body>
    <div id="boxes">
     <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="app">
       <li class="">
        <a>
         <xsl:attribute name="href">
          javascript:select('<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>')
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </a>
        <br/>
        <xsl:value-of select="desc"/>
       </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="app">
 </xsl:template match="app>
</stylesheet>
```

Can you guys please help me out by letting me know where to do what? Please don't flame me too hard. I'm on an internship and taught myself HTML, CSS, XML, and XSLT this week.

Edit:
Desired output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>Script goes here. This is what I need</script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- This div is for filtering pane-->
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>Category 1</h2>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      Cat1Val1
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      Cat1Val2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Category 2</h2>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      Cat2Val1
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      Cat2Val2
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
  
<!-- This div contains apps that are present still (their categories remain checked) -->
<div>
  <div>
    <h4>App Name</h4>
    <p>App Description</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>App 1 Name</h4>
    <p>App 1 Description</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>App 2 Name</h4>
    <p>App 2 Description</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*I want to have checkboxes for each value within each category.*" Could you post the HTML code you would like to get as the result of the XSL transformation? -- Note that the input you show us is not a well-formed XML document, on account of lacking a single root element.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your question. If I knew the HTML code that I would get, I wouldn't be asking the question? I'm just trying to figure out whether to show each "app" based on whether the checkboxes pertaining to its characteristic categories are checked or not. Thanks. I've been learning JS over the last day or so but I'm not sure how you can use JS to make not text (eg: "this is a string") show/hide but instead html generated from xml (eg: <xsl:value-of select="current()").

Comment: This is my plan:
Loop through each app {
    Loop through each category {
        Loop through each value {
            If value's checkbox is checked from fields {
                Show app, desc
            } Else {
                 Hide
            }
}
}
}

Comment: My question was regarding your **output**.

Comment: Michael, I have added the desired output. Thanks

Comment: Yes, but I cannot see the connection between the input and the output. And your input is still not valid XML.